# Create a 4-condition IF statement to display a certain value in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to do something which I *hope* will be reasonably straightforward in Microsoft Excel. I'm using 2010.

I have two columns called `Username` and `Year Group`.

`Username` takes the format of something like, `11rennem01` or `10oxbech1`. `Year Group` is just a single digit figure, one of `5`/`6`/`7`/`8`.

In a third column, I would like to display the students' shared drives, which take the following format: `\\server\student\`**`IntakeYear`**`\`**`Username`**`. For example, the aforementioned students' paths will be:

(Year 5) `11rennem01` -> `\\server\student\Intake2011\11rennem01`
(Year 6) `10oxbech1` -> `\\server\student\Intake2010\10oxbech1`
(Year 7) `09clarco01` -> `\\server\student\Intake2009\09clarco01`
(Year 8) `08wilkbe01` -> `\\server\student\Intake2008\08wilkbe01`

Unfortunately, despite the numbers `11` and `10` at the start of the students' usernames matching up, **there's a possibility, with a few students, that the number at the start of their username will be different to their Intake Year**. As such, the only reliable value is the `Year Group` figure in the second column.

How can I go about writing such an IF statement?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Wouldn't 2003 + Year Group work, instead of an if statement? Or is it more complicated than that? A nested if is possible, but the nesting depth is limited to 7 AFAIK, which might be problematic three years from now.

Comment: Unfortunately not - I'll update my post so you can see why. Apologies, think I had one of the network paths wrong too. Doh! Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming cell A1=Username, cell B1=Year Group, then in cell C1 you should write:

`="\\server\student\Intake"&IF(B1=5;"2011";IF(B1=6;"2010";IF(B1=7;"2009";"2008")))&"\"&A1`

and then copy cell C1 into as many cells of row C as you need

Answer (score 2):

In column three enter the following code:

```
="\\server\student\Intake"&2016-B7&"\"&A7
```

Your output will be:

```
Username    Year Group  SharedDrive

11rennem01  5          \\server\student\Intake2011\11rennem01
```

Answer (score 1):

change it from IF, which tends to look horrible once you nest a few.

As you have a small start point, I would use `CHOOSE`. In your case, use
`=CHOOSE(A2,"Invalid","Invalid","Invalid","Invalid","2008","2009","2010","2011")`
to construct the directory

Answer (score 0):

I'd use either the LOOKUP function with a small table mapping Intake Years to share folders (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324986), or a big IF like this:

```
=IF(A2 = "Year 5", "Intake2011", IF(A2 = "Year 6", "Intake2010", IF(A2 = "Year 7", "Intake2009", "Intake2008")))
```

The lookup table solution is better though, in my opinion.